# Illustrator background gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

Hi everyone I'm trying to add a gradient to a design. I'm wanting to basically keep the inside gradient and get rid of the outside (image 1).

[image]

I've tried lots of different ways using a clipping mask. My process:

- Grouped image
- Made mask
- Selected right window in Transparency
- In Transparency unchecked 'Clip', checked 'Invert Mask'
- Pasted in colour background over grouped design
- Clicked grey space next to image

In my second image you can see something has applied but all I get is low opacity gradient of some sort (image 2).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mask is not made correctly.

Apply the mask to the gradient square. Must contain the drawing in black and a bottom white frame bigger than the gradient area. With this you get the gradient "perforated" with the design. If you want it reverse, click **Invert mask**.

[image: mask]

This is the mask: a white square on the bottom and the black drawing on top:

[image: mask content]

But for this you don't need a mask,
select the drawing > **Menu Object** > **Compound Path** > **Make** > and apply the gradient fill to the new compound path

Comment: Wow! Danielllo thats exactly what I wanted to achieve. I've just followed your instruction and got it right. Thank you for your quick response and helping me complete my design. Been searching all day for the solution.